# Find eni to resource?

Tags: amazon-vpc

I have two eni, I want to delete, but I don't know how I know to which resource they belong.

When I delete my vpc, I get the following message:

> The following 2 network interfaces must be deleted before this VPC can be deleted:

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't know how I know to which resource they belong

If the error spits out the network interface ID then check them in `EC2 console > Network & Security > Network Interfaces` where you can see to which resources they are associated.

Or you can use [ec2 describe-network-interfaces](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-network-interfaces.html) and filter with `eni-id` or `vpc-id` so see all the network interfaces within the VPC and where they are attached to.

Comment: In EC2 console > Network > Interfaces , it does not show, that this is an interface for example of an Active Directory service.